# Why is no output files written in prinseqlite perl loop?

Tags: perl, file, loops, output, sh

I am completely new to this type of coding/command lines, so I am sorry if I am asking this question in a wrong way.

I want to loop over all files in a directory (I am quality trimming DNA sequencing files (.fastq format))

I have written this loop:

```
for i in *.fastq; do
perl /apps/prinseqlite/0.20.4/prinseq-lite.pl -fastq $i -min_len 220 -max_len 240 -min_qual_mean 30  -ns_max_n 5 -trim_tail_right 15 -trim_tail_left 15 -out_good /proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/$i_filtered.fastq -out_bad null; done
```

The code itself seems to work, I can see in my terminal that it is taking the right files and it is doing the trimming (it is writing a summary log in the terminal as it goes), but no output files are generated  - i.e these ones:

```
-out_good /proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/$i_filtered.fastq
```

If I run the code in a non-loop way, just on one file it works (= the output is generated). link this example:

```
prinseq-lite.pl -fastq 60782_merged_rRNA.fastq -min_len 220 -max_len 240 -min_qual_mean 30  -ns_max_n 5 -trim_tail_right 15 -trim_tail_left 15 -out_good 60782_merged_rRNA_filt_codeTEST.fastq -out_bad null
```

Is there a simple reason/answer to this?

Comment: "*If I run the code in a non-loop way*" - what's the exact command line you're using?

Comment: Hi, I edited to post incl. the code line that works - was this what you meant?

Comment: @melpomene I think she runs it on a single file, instead of `$i` _EDIT_: there I see it is edited.

Comment: @Mathilde yes, that is what he asked :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, but how? From the edit you can see that the `-out_file` argument is completely different (e.g. no `_filtered`).

Comment: @melpomene yes, I see that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Perl at all.

`/proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/$i_filtered.fastq` is read by the shell as interpolating the contents of `i_filtered`. There is no such shell variable, so this argument turns into `/proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/.fastq` (`$i_filtered` turns into nothing).

Therefore all of your `prinseq-lite.pl` executions place their output in the same file, which (because its name starts with a `.`) is "hidden": You need to use `ls -a` to see it, not just `ls`.

Fix

```
... -out_good /proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/${i}_filtered.fastq
```

Note that this would give you e.g. `60782_merged_rRNA.fastq_filtered.fastq` for an input file of `60782_merged_rRNA.fastq`. If you want to get rid of the duplicate `.fastq` part, you need something like:

```
... -out_good /proj/forhot/qfiltered/looptest/"${i%.fastq}"_filtered.fastq
```

Comment: You guys are amazing! - THANK you. I cant get the reduction of ".fastq" to work though, but this is really a minor thing.